# Windows 7 and c++ : Cross compiling application for use on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi

I recently got a Raspberry Pi and I've installed the Raspbian “wheezy” image onto it. My main development machine is running Windows 7, and I'm using Qt Creator as my development environment. I'm trying to find a tool chain that my main computer can use to compile my c++ application for the Raspberry Pi. I've looked all over the place for tutorials and articles on how to do this but all I can find is tutorials for compiling from linux to windows. Which is the opposite of what I'm trying to do. I also noticed that there's a image available that comes with the Qt SDK but I'd rather use the Raspbian image for now. Has anyone been able to find a way get there programs from windows to there Pi? I'm a serious novice when it come's to cross-compiling. D:

Comment: there is a stack overflow for raspberry pi , you might want to ask this there

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I to have recently got myself a Raspberry Pi.

I normally develop in Java and use NetBeans, but started using NetBeans to develop C and C++ applications. To do this I have installed Cygwin on my Windows 7 to be able to compile windows based applications.

However, I can also compile my application for my Raspberry Pi using the same NetBeans IDE.  All I had to do was right-click on the project name in NetBeans, select `Set build host`, then `Manage Hosts` and a dialog will be displayed. Select `Add` and enter your Raspberry Pi IP Address in the hostname-field, then click `Next`.

Netbeans will try to establish a connection to the Raspberry Pi via SSH so you must ensure that SSH is enabled. Enter you Raspberry Pi user name in the login-field and click `Next` again. You will be prompted to confirm the SSH keys and enter the Raspberry Pi user name.

Now just confirm the details, click finish, and have fun.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't find anything you could just use a VM. (Virtual Machine)

Run Linux on it and make a shared folder where you put your project. So you just have to switch to linux for compiling ;)

An other thing would be to have a look at cygwin. It's a complete Linux shell including gcc. So probably you could use that.

Look at these VM if you're interested in it:
-[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)
-[Microsoft Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx)

Comment: Try Linux Mint (http://linuxmint.com/) for a distro that looks a lot like Windows to ease you into Linux land.